Does the SRAT show offline memory?
I'm reading this section of the ACPI documentation on the SRAT: https://uefi.org/htmlspecs/ACPI_Spec_6_4_html/17_NUMA_Architecture_Platforms/NUMA_Architecture_Platforms.html#system-resource-affinity-table-definition .
There's this sentence:
The optional System Resource Affinity Table (SRAT) provides the boot time description of the processor and memory ranges belonging to a system locality. 

Further below in the same section there's this other sentence:
The SRAT describes the system locality that all processors and memory present in a system belong to at system boot. This includes memory that can be hot-added (that is memory that can be added to the system while it is running, without requiring a reboot). 

The statements "The SRAT describes the system locality that all processors and memory present in a system belong to at system boot" and "This includes memory that can be hot-added" intuitively seems to contradict themselves.
The only interpretation that I can think of that doesn't lead to a contradiction is that if there are memory DIMMs that are offline/not used by the kernel since boot time, (a) they will be listed in the SRAT and (b) they can be "activated" (i.e. made to be considered by the kernel) without requiring a system reboot.
Is my interpretation correct or am I missing something?
